# How to replace text among numbers within object feature

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an object feature "Year-Of-Publication" which I'd like to convert into numeric type. The feature contains values like 2009, 2018, 1995, ... DK-Something, ... I think I need to find all strings within the feature and replace them with some default, but I don't know how to do that practically.

I've tried:

```
data = data['Year-Of-Publication'].astype(int)
```

...which raises:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'DK Publishing
>   Inc'

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

The attribute looks like:

```
books['Year-Of-Publication'].head()

0    2002
1    2001
2    1991
3    1999
4    1999
Name: Year-Of-Publication, dtype: object
```

I want to convert it into numeric type but the problem is it contains strings as well, e.g. value 'DK Publishing Inc'.

Comment: Can you please add some code on what data you have and what output do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas.to_numeric` with `fillna`:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([2009, 2018, 1995, 'DK-Something'])
pd.to_numeric(s, 'coerce').fillna(-1, downcast = 'infer')
```

Output:

```
0    2009
1    2018
2    1995
3      -1
dtype: int64
```

Here the value of `fillna` (i.e. `-1`) is the default replacement of your choice.

Comment: What do 'coerse'  and downcast='infer' mean?

Comment: @StanislavJirák Sorry for typo. It is `coerce`. It means that [If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaN](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html). `downcast='infer'` means that after filling the series, `pandas` will try to change the data type to the smallest dtype possible.

Comment: Thanks. Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

Specify a range of allowed values, in this case a range of valid years. All values not in that range can be replaced by a default value of your choice:

```
import pandas as pd

# Just some made up data
df = pd.DataFrame({'year-of-publication': [2009, 2018, 1995, 'DK-1235', 2005, 'ssjdk']})

# Select all rows that don't have valid years, in this case ranging from 1900 to 2019
# and set them to your default value, in this case 2000
df.loc[~df['year-of-publication'].isin(list(range(1900,2020)))] = 2000 
print(df)
```